# Crystal Enterprise - Business Objects - is there a similar alternative?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting-services, reporting

We are reviewing our need for Crystal Enterprise - Business Objects.  Our requirements are to have a way for users to login and choose from an selection of reports dependant on what they have access to.  These reports are all designed in Crystal Reports and link to various databases.  Are there any enterprise type solutions for hosting reports that people can recommend?  I'm aware of SSRS and we are exploring that tool but want to know of others out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cognos](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/cognos)
[MicroStrategy](http://www.microstrategy.com)
[Hyperion](http://www.oracle.com/hyperion)
[Jasper](http://www.jaspersoft.com/)

Brio was acquired by Hyperion.